# D3 Rotating text around a pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to rotate and position text elements around a circle
I currently have the following data structure:

```
<g class="node" transform="translate(670.9158935546875,154.62908935546875)">
<circle r="5"></circle>
<text x="7" y="3" class="text" transform="rotate(-69.54545454545455)" title="20.454545454545457" style="text-anchor: start;">
  Syrian Arab Republic 
</text>
</g>
```

I use the pie layout to position the g nodes that contain the circle and text on a circle.

Then I use the following Code to rotate the labels

```
d3.selectAll(".text")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.angle - 90) + ")" +  ((d.angle>180)? "rotate(180)" : "")  })
  .style("text-anchor", function(d) { 
  return (d.angle > 180 ? "end" : "start"); });
```

Which gives me this output:

http://postimg.org/image/sgwv8uxax/

As you can see the position of the texts on the left side of the circle is off :(

Could somebody give me a hint on how I can evenly correct this position?
Ideally without changing the XML datastructure layout.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Add a horizontal offset if the `text-anchor` is `end`, e.g. `.attr("dx", function(d) { return (d.angle > 180 ? 10 : 0); })`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of solving this is to simply add a horizontal offset when `text-anchor` is `end`:

```
.attr("dx", function(d) { return (d.angle > 180 ? 10 : 0); })
```